# trim property of specific object inside array of objects

Tags: javascript

Question: How to iterate through an array of objects and trim-specific property of an object?

Need to update the array of objects, to update every property in objects inside an array.

I need to delete white spaces (trim) accountId and handlerId properties in every object.

Here is a code example of what I tried:

```
// This is an array of objects
var data = [
  { 
    Company: "Church Mutual",
    accountId: "1234567  ",  <======= need to trim()
    accountName: "Test123",
    handlerId: "1111111  ",   <======= need to trim()
    lineOfBusiness: "WC",
    selectedState: "NY",
    tpa: "No",
  },
   { 
    Company: "Church Mutual",
    accountId: "1234567  ",
    accountName: "Test123",
    handlerId: "1111111  ",
    lineOfBusiness: "WC",
    selectedState: "NY",
    tpa: "No",
  }
];

var newData = data.forEach(i => {
 data[i].accountId.trim()
})
```

Any advice or help is welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate over array of objects and change one property in each object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306471/iterate-over-array-of-objects-and-change-one-property-in-each-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String#trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) returns the changed value. Since the array members are objects, you can directly modify the key, and assign the trimmed value. Moreover, `i` is the item, not the index, so you can directly access the properties on `i`, instead of `data[i]`. See documentation of [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

**Note**: If you don't want to change the original items, you need to [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) the array first, and then apply the `forEach` loop over copied object.

```js
// This is array of objects
var data = [{
    Company: "Church Mutual",
    accountId: "1234567  ",
    accountName: "Test123",
    handlerId: "1111111  ",
    lineOfBusiness: "WC",
    selectedState: "NY",
    tpa: "No",
  },
  {
    Company: "Church Mutual",
    accountId: "1234567  ",
    accountName: "Test123",
    handlerId: "1111111  ",
    lineOfBusiness: "WC",
    selectedState: "NY",
    tpa: "No",
  }
];

data.forEach(i => {
  i.accountId = i.accountId.trim();
  i.handlerId = i.handlerId.trim();
})

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `forEach` and `Object.entries`

```js
var data = [
  { 
    Company: "Church Mutual",
    accountId: "1234567  ",
    accountName: "Test123",
    handlerId: "1111111  ",
    lineOfBusiness: "WC",
    selectedState: "NY",
    tpa: "No",
  },
   { 
    Company: "Church Mutual",
    accountId: "1234567  ",
    accountName: "Test123",
    handlerId: "1111111  ",
    lineOfBusiness: "WC",
    selectedState: "NY",
    tpa: "No",
  }
];

data.forEach(e => {
  Object.entries(e).forEach(([key,value])=>{
    e[key] = value.trim()
  })
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `map`:

```js
var data = [
  { 
    Company: "Church Mutual",
    accountId: "1234567  ",  
    accountName: "Test123",
    handlerId: "1111111  ",   
    lineOfBusiness: "WC",
    selectedState: "NY",
    tpa: "No",
  },
   { 
    Company: "Church Mutual",
    accountId: "1234567  ",
    accountName: "Test123",
    handlerId: "1111111  ",
    lineOfBusiness: "WC",
    selectedState: "NY",
    tpa: "No",
  }
];

var newData = data.map(o => {
 o.accountId = o.accountId.trim();
 o.handlerId = o.handlerId.trim();
 return o;
});

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array of the wanted keys for trimming and iterate the objects and the keys and assign the trimmed values.

```js
var data = [{ Company: "Church Mutual", accountId: "1234567  ", accountName: "Test123", handlerId: "1111111  ", lineOfBusiness: "WC", selectedState: "NY", tpa: "No" }, { Company: "Church Mutual", accountId: "1234567  ", accountName: "Test123", handlerId: "1111111  ", lineOfBusiness: "WC", selectedState: "NY", tpa: "No" }],
    keys = ['accountId', 'handlerId'];

data.forEach(o => keys.forEach(k => o[k] = o[k].trim()));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `forEach` method by passing a *callback* function as argument.

```js
var data = [ { Company: "Church Mutual", accountId: "1234567 ", accountName: "Test123", handlerId: "1111111 ", lineOfBusiness: "WC", selectedState: "NY", tpa: "No", }, { Company: "Church Mutual", accountId: "1234567 ", accountName: "Test123", handlerId: "1111111 ", lineOfBusiness: "WC", selectedState: "NY", tpa: "No", } ];

data.forEach(item => { 
    Object.keys(item).forEach(key => { 
        item[key] = item[key].trim()
    });
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var data = [{
    Company: "Church Mutual",
    accountId: "1234567  ",
    accountName: "Test123",
    handlerId: "1111111  ",
    lineOfBusiness: "WC",
    selectedState: "NY",
    tpa: "No",
  },
  {
    Company: "Church Mutual",
    accountId: "1234567  ",
    accountName: "Test123",
    handlerId: "1111111  ",
    lineOfBusiness: "WC",
    selectedState: "NY",
    tpa: "No",
  }
];
```

```
const trimmer = (data, fields) => data.map(o => fields.reduce((acc, field) => Object.assign(acc, {[field]: acc[field].trim()}),o))
```

and use it like this:

```
const newData = trimmer(data, ['accountId', 'handlerId'])
```